# BlackBerry - read custom ringtone name from address book contact list?

Tags: blackberry, integration, addressbook, ringtone, contact-list

Actually I am assigning custom ringtone with contact number in a custom database contact list.
Now I am having problem with the reading to that contact list.
If anyone having any idea about this problem pls pls help.

**UPDATE**

```
public void showAddressBook() {
    try {
        ContactList contactList = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance()
                .openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
        Enumeration enumx = contactList.items();
        while (enumx.hasMoreElements()) {
            Contact c = (Contact) enumx.nextElement();
            int[] fieldIds = c.getFields();
            System.out.println("SHOW:" + c.EXTENDED_FIELD_MIN_VALUE);
            int id;
            for (int index = 0; index < fieldIds.length; ++index) {
                id = fieldIds[index];
                System.out.println(c.getPIMList().getFieldLabel(id)
                        + "==showAddressBook==" + fieldIds.length);
                if (c.getPIMList().getFieldDataType(id) == Contact.STRING) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < c.countValues(id); ++j) {
                        String value = c.getString(id, j);
                        System.out.println(c.getPIMList().getFieldLabel(id)
                                + "=" + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PIMException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the custom database contact list? How you assign custom ringtone to contact? Can you post code?

Comment: Ok not to discuss about custom database!!!
Actually i am trying to get CustomPhoneTone from blackberry default address book. My main goal to get that custom ringtone field which I have assigned to a partcular contact number during editing the contact list and personized one's tone. 
Below code doesnot show me the added custom tone field:

public void showAddressBook() {
        try {
           
            ContactList contactList = (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
            PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
            Enumeration enumx = contactList.items();
 continue...

Comment: while (enumx.hasMoreElements())
            {
                Contact c = (Contact)enumx.nextElement();
                int[] fieldIds = c.getFields();
                System.out.println("SHOW:"+c.EXTENDED_FIELD_MIN_VALUE );
                int id;
                for(int index = 0; index < fieldIds.length; ++index) {
                    id = fieldIds[index];
                    System.out.println(c.getPIMList().getFieldLabel(id)+"==showAddressBook=="+fieldIds.length);

Comment: if(c.getPIMList().getFieldDataType(id) == Contact.STRING)
                    {
                        for(int j=0; j < c.countValues(id); ++j) {
                            String value = c.getString(id, j);
                            System.out.println(c.getPIMList().getFieldLabel(id) + "=" + value);
                        }
                    }
                   
                }
            }           
        } catch (PIMException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
}

Comment: Please check this code as u said very helpful for me...Thanks

Comment: Hi viewers!


CUSTOM_TUNE_NAME - Static variable in interface net.rim.device.api.notification.NotificationsConstants.
Context key to indicate there is a custom tune for this incoming message/call

 

Can anyone show me the path, how would I use this static variable to access my custome ringtone field

which I have added as a personalized tone in my Contact list.


Please anyone show me the path very much thankful to u.

If possible write with small code as example.


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference to Contact Custom Ringtone in RIM API documentation...

> This is not exposed in the Contact or BlackBerryContact class.  There is no API to access the ring tone for a contact.
>   Mark Sohm
>   BlackBerry Development Advisor
>   www.BlackBerryDeveloper.com

[BlackBerry Support Community Forums:Java Development:Re: Custom ringtone field in Contacts](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ringtone-field-in-Contacts/m-p/32602/highlight/true;jsessionid=3251DCE2B7EA6453177D6565341EDB72)